# Python - Turtle Stop Listening

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

As it says in the title. Is it possible to stop listening in python's turtle module. Example:

```
turtle.onkey(setChar1, '1')
turtle.onkey(setChar2, '2')
turtle.onkey(setChar3, '3')
turtle.listen()
```

But can I do something like `turtle.stopListen()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no obvious `unlisten()` functionality, even if you drop down to the tkinter underpinnings.  I hope someone comes up with one for you.

The way the turtle package seems to want you to do it is:

```
def keys_activate():
    turtle.onkey(setChar1, '1')
    turtle.onkey(setChar2, '2')
    turtle.onkey(setChar3, '3')
    turtle.listen()

def keys_deactivate():
    turtle.onkey(None, '1')
    turtle.onkey(None, '2')
    turtle.onkey(None, '3')
```

Another approach would be to define a global `listening` variable that your key handlers checked to see if they should be active or not.  Something like:

```
from turtle import *

listening = False

def listen(listen_original=listen):
    global listening
    listen_original()
    listening = True

def unlisten():
    global listening
    listening = False

def setChar1():
    if not listening:
        return

    reset()
    for i in range(36):
        forward(200)
        left(170)

def setChar2():
    unlisten()

def setChar3():
    listen() 

onkey(setChar1, '1')
onkey(setChar2, '2')
onkey(setChar3, '3')
listen()

done()
```

Pressing '1' will slowly draw a figure; pressing '1' again will reset the screen and restart drawing the figure.  Pressing '2' will turn off that functionality such that pressing '1' does nothing.  Pressing '3' will turn keys back on so you can again press '1' to restart the drawing.